# ¿Cómo hacer un arreglo de objetos en c++?

Tags: c++, array, poo

Un saludo, debo hacer una clase para manejar los datos de personas (Nombre, Apellido, Edad, Sexo, Dirección, y Teléfono) y mostrarlos en pantalla, utilizando arreglos de objetos. Al crear un arreglo en el programa principal este me manda el siguiente error: `` error: undefined reference to `Personas::Personas() ``

El código que he hecho hasta ahora es el siguiente. No funciona incluso si declaro un objeto normal (que no sea un array).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Personas
{
private:
    int n=0;

public:
    Personas();
    string nombre, apellido, sexo, direccion;
    unsigned int telefono, edad;
    void pidedatos(void);
    void muestradatos(int n);
};


int main()
{
    Personas arrepersons[2];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: El programa funciona cuando le quito el constructor, ¿acaso cuando se usan arreglos de objetos no se debe colocar el constructor?

Comment: Cuando no pones `Personas();` el constructor lo crea tu compilador, por eso no te marca errores. Pero si solo declaras el constructor, y despues no lo no defines (Que es lo que estas haciendo tu), te sale el error. Basicamente el error significa que no puede encontrar la definicion de la funcion.

Comment: El sitio no permite que se coloquen las respuestas dentro de las preguntas en si, y lo mas probable es que un moderador elimine tu edicion. Si lo prefieres, añado lo que puse como respuesta y tu lo marcas como respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca no cerramos una publicacion, salvo que no sea valida para el sitio. En su defecto, acepta la respuesta que te dieron. Aprende a usar el sitio, lee los links que te pase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando no pones `Personas();` el constructor lo crea tu compilador, por eso no te marca errores.

Pero si solo declaras el constructor, y despues no lo no defines (Que es lo que estas haciendo tu), te sale el error.

Basicamente el error significa que no puede encontrar la definicion de la funcion.

```
class A {
  public:
   A(); // <- Si lo dejas solo asi te marca el error
}

A::A() {} // Y se soluciona cuando defines el constructor.
```

**Nota:** Si el constructor no va a hacer nada, es mejor que dejes que lo haga el compilador.

Comment: La proxima vez, puedes editar la publicacion y revertir la edicion. Enseñar a los usuarios a usar el sitio tambien sirve :)